# Mocha object diff in junit style reports

Tags: mocha.js, circleci

We've just moved our tests onto CircleCI, we're using mocha.
The majority of our tests are checking if the JSON object returned by our API is correct, so we're relying heavily on the output of `chai-subset`

I just set up the `mocha-junit-reporter` and to my disappointment discovered that it does not save the object diffs in the report it creates.

Is there a way to get this information into such reports?

I know I can set up the `mocha-jenkins-reporter` to create spec and junit reports, but seems like a bit of a waste to even have the junit reports if they don't contain the most useful debugging information.